# how to get longitude and latitude using ConvertPlaceToLonLat

Tags: windows-phone-7, latitude-longitude

how to get the `latitude` and `longitude` values form `ConvertPlaceToLonLat` method of [this service Reference](http://msrmaps.com/TerraService2.asmx)